# Publishing jasmine test results using CI on TFS

Tags: node.js, tfs, jasmine, continuous-integration, chai

I have created some tests using jasmine and chai for my nodejs application. I am looking at publishing the test results in TFS using CI build. Could somebody give me direction on how to go about it.

Example of the test that I have written

```
import chai from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import  financialMapper from "../map/mappers/party-financials.mapper";
import * as _ from 'lodash';

var assert = chai.assert;
var expect = chai.expect;

let financials = { key: 160233,
  data:
   [ { companyId: 160233,
       dataItemName: 'Cash and Cash Equivalents, Beginning of Period',
       dataItemId: 2055,
       dataItemvalueUSD: 207217000,
       fiscalYear: 2016,
       periodTypeId: 4,
       fiscalQuarter: 4 },
     { companyId: 160233,
       dataItemName: 'Preferred Dividend and Other Adjustments',
       dataItemId: 97,
       dataItemvalueUSD: 405000,
       fiscalYear: 2016,
       periodTypeId: 4,
       fiscalQuarter: 4 },
     { companyId: 160233,
       dataItemName: 'Basic Earnings Per Share - Total',
       dataItemId: 3523,
       dataItemvalueUSD: 0.43728,
       fiscalYear: 2016,
       periodTypeId: 4,
       fiscalQuarter: 4 },
     { companyId: 160233,
       dataItemName: 'Net Property Plant And Equipment',
       dataItemId: 1004,
       periodTypeId: 4,
       dataItemvalueUSD: 123269000,
       fiscalYear: 2016,
       fiscalQuarter: 4 },
     { companyId: 160233,
       dataItemName: 'Accounts Receivable, Total',
       dataItemId: 1021,
       dataItemvalueUSD: 892289000,
       fiscalYear: 2016,
       periodTypeId: 4,
       fiscalQuarter: 4 },
     { companyId: 160233,
       dataItemName: 'Net Income - (IS)',
       dataItemId: 15,
       dataItemvalueUSD: 65517000,
       fiscalYear: 2016,
       periodTypeId: 4,
       fiscalQuarter: 4 },
     { companyId: 160233,
       dataItemName: 'Accounts Payable, Total',
       dataItemId: 1018,
       dataItemvalueUSD: 246670000,
       fiscalYear: 2016,
       periodTypeId: 4,
       fiscalQuarter: 4 },
     { companyId: 160233,
       dataItemName: 'Interest Expense',
       dataItemId: 208,
       dataItemvalueUSD: -17878000,
       fiscalYear: 2016,
       periodTypeId: 4,
       fiscalQuarter: 4 }]}


describe('party financials mapper test suit:', function () {

    it('should return an array of financials items', function () {
        let doc = financialMapper.map(financials).value[0]
        assert.isArray(doc);
    });
  it('should return financials with period id equal to 4', function () {
    let doc = financialMapper.map(financials).value[0]
    assert.equal(doc[0].historical[0].periodTypeId,4);
  });

    it('should return financials item with name equal to : <Interest Expense>', function () {
        let docs= financialMapper.map(financials).value[0]

        let doc = _.find(docs, (item)=>{
            return item.name==='Interest Expense'
        })
        assert.isTrue(doc.name==='Interest Expense');
    });
    it('should return financials item with data item id equal to: <208>', function () {
        let docs= financialMapper.map(financials).value[0]

        let doc = _.find(docs, (item)=>{
            return item.name==='Interest Expense'
        })
        assert.equal(doc.dataItemId,208);
    });

    it('should return financials item with current value equal to :<-17878000>', function () {
        let docs= financialMapper.map(financials).value[0]

        let doc = _.find(docs, (item)=>{
            return item.name==='Interest Expense'
        })
        assert.equal(doc.current,-17878000);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used [this](https://github.com/sgbj/jasmine-tfs-reporter) package before. The example shows how to set it up for protractor but you can do the same thing with karma or whatever test runner you are using. Just set it up as a reporter so that it creates the xml file and then add the build step to publish the results.

Comment: Is this example used only for angular projects. The project that i am working on is nodejs project

Comment: How are you running the tests right now? I have only used it with angular unit tests running with karma but it should work with any test runner that allows you to add a reporter to the config. Otherwise, you could probably fork the repo and customize it for what you need.

Comment: I am not using angular application. I have created a node js application. I am running the commands via the command prompt

Comment: If so, you can create a junit test report by passing the `--junitreporter` flag. You will then need to convert that file to a .trx so that TFS will understand it. Try looking for a package that can convert an XML file to a .trx file. I looked briefly but some of the tools I found seem outdated.